How do I match one index to another that is written in different form (with "-" or with spaces)?
How do I find index from column A in column B and return said index from column B into column D? For example: I want to search index 92406A2000

I have tried XMatch, match, search, find, vlookup for approximate matches but it doesn't work.

Show us the formulas you tried, what are the results you are getting, what is the desired output?

With the given data sample, this works:
=XLOOKUP(IF(ISNUMBER($D$96:$D$101),$D$96:$D$101,SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($D$96:$D$101," ",""),"-","")),$A$96:$A$101,$B$96:$B$101)

I encountered one problem, when your lookup list (column A) is numerical, but your lookup value isn't, it causes an error:


So, this works on my end, using XLOOKUP() with a combination of TEXTSPLIT()+CONCAT()


• Formula used in cell E1
=XLOOKUP(CONCAT(TEXTSPLIT(D1,{" ","-"})),$A$1:$A$6&"",$B$1:$B$6,"")


The cell D4 returns empty since it can't find similar value in the Lookup_Array

From the new post answer of OP, a screenshot is updated where there is a clinical mismatch for 92406-A2-000 however it has been shown to find the exact match. Not sure whether it is a typo or something. The following should work, if there is a match.
Per OP:

This formula searches for Index from master list in column D which has
more than 8500 rows in a list of indexes in column A that changes
every day and returns a value from column B. What I need is to search
for index from column A in master list in column D and return said
value form column D to column E. Please see my answer that has a
picture of what I need




=IF(SUM(N(CONCAT(TEXTSPLIT(D1,{" ","-"}))=$A$1:$A$6)),D1,"")



This formula searches for Index from master list in column D which has more than 8500 rows in a list of indexes in column A that changes every day and returns a value from column B. What I need is to search for index from column A in master list in column D and return said value form column D to column E. Please see my answer that has a picture of what I need.
